# Why am I getting zero in the output?

Tags: c++, arrays, swap

So I'm trying to swap two numbers without using a third variable. I pass the two numbers I'm trying to swap by reference. When the same number is to be swapped (like 1 is to be swapped with 1), I get an output of zero. I know how to fix this, but I'm unable to understand as to why I keep getting 0 when a and b are the same.

Can anyone explain why I'm getting zero instead of the swapped numbers?

```
void swap(int *a,int *b)
{
        //if(a==b)
        //      return;
        *a=*a+*b;
        *b=*a-*b;
        *a=*a-*b;
}
int main()
{
    int n=3,x=0,y=0;
    int a[n][n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                swap(&a[x][i],&a[i][y]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int a[n][n];` isn't valid C++. C++ doesn't support variable-length arrays. You didn't initialize the array. Reading values from `a` causes undefined behavior

Comment: Which numbers do you think `a` contains?

Comment: @U. Watt The code does not make sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: It's unrelated: you're not passing values by reference. You are passing pointers by value. To pass values by reference you would use `void swap(int &a,int &b)` instead.

Comment: Try `int a[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};` instead of `int a[n][n];`

Comment: @ThomasSablik that's passing by reference - that's same thing done by different syntax.

Comment: And the different syntax is called different. The first syntax is called call by value and the second is call by reference.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Richie would argue with you, that reference here means something else.When someone starts with learning C, that's the term they get hammered in head. Even Stroustrup would, though he would say that  abstraction-wise you're right, as C++ references gained more features since he introduced them. Passing by reference isn't syntax-based term, it's a paradigm, meaning that function(subroutine) is able to change it's parameters' value outside of subroutine scope. Term was introduced in pascal, which didn't had references as type.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie In C you could call this call by reference because there is no other way. In C++ real call by reference exists.

Comment: @ThomasSablik it's still pass (call) by reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Did you read your own link? It says that C doesn't support call by reference and simulates it with pointers. So call by pointer is a simulation of call by reference and doesn't exactly implement it. _It is not a separate evaluation strategy—the language calls by value—but sometimes it is referred to as call by address_

Comment: @ThomasSablik Yes I 've read that as well as multiple others in four last decades. Key words though are  a) it's the name of strategy, there is no "call by pointer" b) it is being simulated. In non-interpreting languages all calls by reference are simulated by call by address in result, including C++. interpreter-based ones, like java, use different approach to refer actual object.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I've learned that programming is an exact discipline. If something is like call by reference but it's not exactly call by reference then it should not be called call by reference. Call by address is not call by reference therefore there are two different names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are trying to swap elements of the first row with elements of the first column.

For starters variable length arrays is not a standard C++ feature. Though some compilers have their own language extensions you should avoid their using.

Also the swap function can have undefined behavior because when there is an overflow of a signed integer then the result is undefined. It is better to use the standard C++ function `std::swap`.
And in your program you are using an uninitialized array.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how you could write the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 3;
    int a[N][N];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            a[i][j] = i * N + j;
        }
    }

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( const auto &item : row )
        {
            std::cout << item << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::swap( a[0][i], a[i][0] );
    }

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( const auto &item : row )
        {
            std::cout << item << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 1 2 
3 4 5 
6 7 8 

0 3 6 
1 4 5 
2 7 8
```

If you want to write your own swap function then write it like

```
void swap( int *a, int *b )
{
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
```

and use it in the program like

```
::swap( &a[0][i], &a[i][0] );
```

Answer (score -4):

As far as  i understood your code.  You are trying to swap first row elements with its corresponding elements in the first column.. 
You are getting 0 at  position a[0][0] in the matrix. 
The reason is simple.. 
Look at this steps in your code
         *b=*a-*b;
        *a=*a-*b;
You are substracting same from that value.. 
Obviously result will be 0.
           And yeh the idea of swapping row with column is really creative